# GAM set a smoothing degree

Tags: r, degrees-of-freedom, generalized-additive-model, deviance

What is the difference between the EDF (effective degree of freedom) and the degree of smoothing in a General Additive Model (GAM)?

For example:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
n  <- 400
x1 <- runif(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(n, 0, 1) 
x3 <- runif(n, 0, 1) 

f1 <- function(x) exp(2 * x) - 3.75887
f2 <- function(x) 0.2*x^11*(10*(1-x))^6+10*(10*x)^3*(1-x)^10
f3 <- function(x) 0.008*x^2 - 1.8*x + 874

f <- f1(x1) + f2(x2) + f3(x3)
e <- rnorm(n, 0, 2)
y <- f + e

b      <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1, k=3) + s(x2, k=3) + s(x3, k=3))
b3     <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1)      + s(x2),                    sp=c(b$sp[1], b$sp[2]))
b3_bis <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1, k=3) + s(x2, k=3),               sp=c(b$sp[1], b$sp[2]))
```

I don't understand how and why the deviance explained by b3 and b3_bis is different. As I set the sp (degree of smoothing) in b3 and b3_bis, how the model can explain more variance in b3_bis? The relationship fitted between y and x1 and x2 are supposed to be the same for b3 and b3_bis.

And I don't understand why x1 and x2 EDF are different between b3 and b3_bis? If the degree of smoothing is effectively identical between b3 and b3_bis, why the EDF is different?